# full width video stretch issue in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I have full width video on website. Its getting stretched not looking good. I have tried this

```
.et_pb_section_video_bg .mejs-video {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
    }
```

But some how its not working. can any body help I have attached snapshot[image]

Comment: This will be perfect working example for you. For full screen you don't have to use so many elements. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp

Comment: You are making it full screen in width, but you are not keeping its aspect ratio. Can you let us know how you want it to appear, e.g. full width even if it doesn’t fit height-ways on the screen? Or should it have a max height? Also, why are you using position absolute - what is the container css?